# How to ensemble two Neural Networks that has been trained differently?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I have created two different Neural Networks that both predict if a team is going to WIN/LOSE a hockey game. The first NN has been trained on 82 features from games that has been played. The other has been trained on 115 features from player stats in all the games that has been played.

Some features are the same in both sets, but the important metrics differ or are represented differently (aggregated/individual)

Is there anyway to ensemble these NNs so that it is possible to just feed it a set containing only two features like this.

```
h_team1   h_team_2    h_team3    a_team1   a_team2    a_team3     WIN/LOSE
   1         0           0          1          0         0
   1         0           0          0          1         0
   0         1           0          0          0         1
```

And the new NN's task will be to classify the probability of the home team winning the game.

If I'm really off with what I'm trying to do, please correct me.

I've added an image to help visualize the problem I'm describing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqydc.jpg (The arrows point to the model I want to build, have not built it, because I do not know how)

EDIT:

Example data from game_DATA-set h=home a=away

```
h_Won/Lost h_powerPlayGoals h_powerPlayPercentage a_powerPlayGoals a_powerPlayPercentage h_team1    h_team 2     a_team1     a_team2     gameID
   1            2                    0.4                1              0.5                      1          0            1          0      1
```

Example data from player_DATA-set

```
Won/Lost   playerID    team1  team2   metric1   opponent1     opponent2    gameID
   1          5678       1       0     10       1              0          1
```

Comment: Can you please give the example of the data from all 3 datasets?

Comment: Sure, of both the datasets? They are from the NHL-API.

Comment: I don't understand why did you train the first 2 models, the ones with 82 an 115 features?

Comment: @Novak I trained the models to do predictions on upcoming NHL games. I couldn't use all the features simultaneously so I trained to models on their respective features.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What I don't understand is why did you train those 2 models if you want to use model that takes only 2 features?

Comment: @Novak Sorry, I belive you are miss-interpreting me, what I want to do is ENSEMBLE the two models I have trained into one, that only takes 2 features. Please tell me if you need further info.

Comment: I think you didn't grasp the concept of ensembles. The point is that you have a few different models that try to predict the same thing and you take into the account all of their opinions and make the decision. It's like the group of people, you value each opinion differently, If you trust someone more, their opinion has more weight for you. But when you hear all the opinions you have to make a decision. In ensembles, you don't do it with NN. You simply have to assign a weight to each opinion and see what comes out. You have binary classification so outputs are `x` and `1-x` and that's it.

Comment: @Novak after reading up on it, i believe you are completely right about me not grasping the concept of ensembles. I also think think that the way I want to solve my problem isn’t implementable, and that I will have to start over using other ML techniques

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you troubleshoot the problem and understand it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle it is possible to feed that into another NN to get a new output but it makes absolutely no sense from a statistics point of view. You predict that your team is gonna win with x probability so the other team wins with 1-x probability. Therefore why would you need another network for this.

By using the softmax on the last layer your output is essentially x and 1-x for your first network and y and 1-y in the second network. Therefore, the only reasonable thing to do for the third network is to check if x > y and output a probability based on the margin between those two, but you can also just do this with a difference instead of a NN and then you do not have to learn anything.

Comment: I see what you are saying, put given the weights of the features in both models, wouldn't they be adjusted to be more precise given that the NN's will learn from each other? That is what I am trying to archive, have the trained NN's learn from each other and output a third NN that only takes the 2 features as stated in the question. Is that possible or even make sense to do?